# Perform large numbers of HTTP requests asyncronously N at a time

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

For some one-time task I need to go through all the records in a database of which there are a few millions, read a value in a cell, make a HTTP request and update another cell which is currently `NULL`.

I want to send all of them by portions, asynchronously, via `asyncio`. And not too many at a time because remote server may ban me: No more than 50 requests/second or at a time.

I've found this code:

```py
import asyncio
import aiohttp


async def one(session, url):
    # request the URL and read it until complete or canceled
    async with session.get(url) as resp:
        await resp.text()


async def fire(urls):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = []
        for url in urls:
            tasks.append(loop.create_task(one(session, url)))

        # 10 seconds
        try:
            await asyncio.wait_for(asyncio.gather(*tasks), timeout=10)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            pass


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(fire([urls...]))
```

But it will send all the request at once.

**How could I do it `N` at *a time*?** Meaning, send `N`, then wait for 1 ... a few or even all of them to return values, then send another lot of `N`... and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Option A: With just `asyncio` in batches

##### Python `<3.11`

```py
from asyncio import create_task, gather, run, sleep

from aiohttp import ClientSession

async def get_one(session: ClientSession, url: str) -> None:
    print("Requesting", url)
    async with session.get(url) as resp:
        text = await resp.text()
        await sleep(2)  # for demo purposes
        print("Got response from", url, text.strip().split("\n", 1)[0])

async def get_all(urls: list[str], num_concurrent: int) -> None:
    url_iterator = iter(urls)
    keep_going = True
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        while keep_going:
            tasks = []
            for _ in range(num_concurrent):
                try:
                    url = next(url_iterator)
                except StopIteration:
                    keep_going = False
                    break
                new_task = create_task(get_one(session, url))
                tasks.append(new_task)
            await gather(*tasks)

async def main() -> None:
    urls = [
        "https://github.com",
        "https://stackoverflow.com",
        "https://python.org",
    ]
    await get_all(urls, 2)

run(main())
```

Output:

```
Requesting https://github.com
Requesting https://stackoverflow.com
Got response from https://github.com <!DOCTYPE html>
Got response from https://stackoverflow.com <!DOCTYPE html>
Requesting https://python.org
Got response from https://python.org <!doctype html>
```

You'll notice that the third requests (to `python.org`) is only sent **after both previous requests have returned a response**. This setup will essentially perform your total number of requests in **batches** of `num_concurrent`.

##### Python `>=3.11`

With the newer `TaskGroup` class, we can make the `get_all` function a bit more concise:

```py
from asyncio import TaskGroup, run, sleep

from aiohttp import ClientSession


async def get_one(session: ClientSession, url: str) -> None:
    ...  # same as above


async def get_all(urls: list[str], num_concurrent: int) -> None:
    url_iterator = iter(urls)
    keep_going = True
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        while keep_going:
            with TaskGroup() as tg:
                for _ in range(num_concurrent):
                    try:
                        url = next(url_iterator)
                    except StopIteration:
                        keep_going = False
                        break
                    tg.create_task(get_one(session, url))

...
```

---

### Option B: With just `asyncio` in a `Queue`

The [`asyncio.Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html) allows us to set a maximum size for it. That makes it possible to limit the maximum number of concurrently executing tasks, but we will need to use the *consumer-producer-pattern*:

```py
from asyncio import Queue, create_task, gather, run, sleep

from aiohttp import ClientSession

async def get_one(session: ClientSession, url: str) -> None:
    ...  # same as above

STOP_SENTINEL = object()

async def consumer(session: ClientSession, q: Queue[str]) -> None:
    url = await q.get()
    while url is not STOP_SENTINEL:
        await get_one(session, url)
        q.task_done()
        url = await q.get()
    q.task_done()

async def main() -> None:
    urls = [
        "https://github.com",
        "https://stackoverflow.com",
        "https://python.org",
    ]
    num_concurrent = 2
    q = Queue(maxsize=num_concurrent)
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        consumers = [
            create_task(consumer(session, q))
            for _ in range(num_concurrent)
        ]
        for url in urls:
            await q.put(url)
        for _ in range(num_concurrent):
            await q.put(STOP_SENTINEL)
        await gather(*consumers)

run(main())
```

Output:

```
Requesting https://github.com
Requesting https://stackoverflow.com
Got response from https://github.com <!DOCTYPE html>
Requesting https://python.org
Got response from https://stackoverflow.com <!DOCTYPE html>
Got response from https://python.org <!doctype html>
```

As you can see now, that third request can be sent **as soon as either of the previous two returns with a response**.

That may be more efficient, even though the setup is a bit more cumbersome.

---

### Option C: With an extra package

I used to run into similar issues with setting a fixed number of `asyncio` tasks to work on a large number of *actual* tasks. To make this easier I wrote the [**`asyncio-taskpool`**](https://github.com/daniil-berg/asyncio-taskpool) package. With it I can do something like this:

```py
from asyncio import run, sleep

from aiohttp import ClientSession
from asyncio_taskpool import TaskPool

async def get_one(session: ClientSession, url: str) -> None:
    ...  # same as above

async def get_all(urls: list[str], num_concurrent: int) -> None:
    pool = TaskPool()
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        pool.starmap(
            get_one,
            ((session, url) for url in urls),
            num_concurrent=num_concurrent,
        )
        await pool.gather_and_close()

async def main() -> None:
    urls = [
        "https://github.com",
        "https://stackoverflow.com",
        "https://python.org",
    ]
    await get_all(urls, 2)

run(main())
```

Output: (same as with the `Queue` approach)

```
Requesting https://github.com
Requesting https://stackoverflow.com
Got response from https://github.com <!DOCTYPE html>
Requesting https://python.org
Got response from https://stackoverflow.com <!DOCTYPE html>
Got response from https://python.org <!doctype html>
```

You'll notice again that the third request will only be made after **at least one of the other two** returns with a response.

You can try that out with larger numbers of tasks. The number being executed concurrently at any given time will never exceed `num_concurrent` as passed to [`map`](https://asyncio-taskpool.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/asyncio_taskpool.pool.html#asyncio_taskpool.pool.TaskPool.map) ([`starmap`](https://asyncio-taskpool.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/asyncio_taskpool.pool.html#asyncio_taskpool.pool.TaskPool.starmap) is just a variant of `map`).

I tried to emulate the standard [`multiprocessing.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) interface to an extent and find this more convenient to use, especially with long-running tasks.