# Is there a way to return values using a TaskPool when making a large number of HTTP requests with asyncio/aiohttp?

Tags: python-asyncio, python-3.8, aiohttp

This question is related to this one: [perform-large-numbers-of-http-requests-asyncronously-n-at-a-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76302813/perform-large-numbers-of-http-requests-asyncronously-n-at-a-time)
The problem is that I want to make a large amount of requests, about 500.000, each request get a json file. In terms of memory all these json files are about 8 GiB.
What I have seen is that if I deal with all these requests with a simple asyncio/aiohttp without considering tasks I will go OOM.

To let you better understand what I am talking about:

```
async def get(session, headers, body):
  async with session.get(url='someURL',headers = headers, json = body) as response:
    resp = await response.json()
      
  return resp

async def main(bodies,headers):
  async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=aiohttp.TCPConnector(ssl=False)) as session:
    data = await asyncio.gather(*[get(session, headers, body) for body in bodies])

  return data

headers = 'some_headers'
bodies  = ['list of dictionaries where each dictionary is a body for the request']

data = asyncio.run(main(bodies,headers))

# Other operations with data
```

Hence, I decided to follow other routes. I tried to apply the different solutions provided in the related question mentioned above without success.
I think, also based on this article [making-an-infinite-number-of-requests-with-python-aiohttp](https://medium.com/@cgarciae/making-an-infinite-number-of-requests-with-python-aiohttp-pypeln-3a552b97dc95) (in which there are some mistakes in the code) that solution C) is the best in terms of memory used, but here comes the problem, I cannot find a way to return the results from the tasks, I can only print them.
I can pass the print output to a variable, but I find it to be quite bad.

Here I also provide the implementations with `asyncio-taskpool` and the one creating my own Taskpool

asyncio-taskpool:

```
from asyncio_taskpool import TaskPool 

async def get(session, headers, body):
  async with session.get(url='someURL',headers = headers, json = body,timeout = None) as response:
    resp = await response.json()
  return resp

async def get_all(bodies, headers, limit_concurrent_tasks):
  pool = TaskPool()
  async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=aiohttp.TCPConnector(ssl=False)) as session:
    pool.starmap(get,((session,headers,body) for body in bodies), num_concurrent = limit_concurrent_tasks)
    return await pool.gather_and_close()


async def main(bodies,headers):
  limit_concurrent_tasks = 1000
  return await get_all(bodies,headers,limit_concurrent_tasks)

headers = 'some_headers'
bodies  = ['list of dictionaries where each dictionary is a body for the request']

data = asyncio.run(main(bodies,headers))

# printing data I obtain None
```

own Taskpool:

```
class TaskPool(object):


  def __init__(self, workers):
    self._semaphore = asyncio.Semaphore(workers)
    self._tasks = set()


  async def put(self, coro):

    await self._semaphore.acquire()  
    task = asyncio.ensure_future(coro)
    self._tasks.add(task)
    task.add_done_callback(on_task_done)


  def _on_task_done(self, task):
    self._tasks.remove(task)
    self._semaphore.release()
    #I have seen that I can print the results from here with
    #try:
    #   print(task.result())
    #except:
    #   pass

  async def join(self):
    await asyncio.gather(*self._tasks)

  async def __aenter__(self):
    return self


  async def __aexit__(self, exc_type, exc, tb):
    return await self.join()





limit = 100

async def get(session, headers, body):

  async with session.get(url='someURL',headers = headers, json = body, timeout = None) as response:
    resp = await response.json()
  return resp


async def _main(total_requests,bodies,headers):

  async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=aiohttp.TCPConnector(ssl=False)) as session, TaskPool(workers = limit) as tasks:
    for i in range(total_requests):
      data = await tasks.put(get(session,headers,bodies[i]))

  return data
```

NOTE: All of this was done in Python 3.8

Comment: Do you need to parse the Jsons immediately? I'd save the json as is to a disk a process the files afterwards...

Comment: @AndrejKesely Yes, for what i have to do is much more time efficient to parse immediately the jsons and process them, also because i then need to process them as if they are one unique item

Comment: Then I'd create few tasks that download the Json and put them into a queue and  2-3 tasks that read from this queue, parse the json and process the data. That way you're sure that only 2-3 jsons are processed at a time (so on oom kill)

Comment: If it can be useful to anyone, it turned out that the approach appears to be correct, but the amount of data downloaded is too much for the hardware at disposal. The solution has been to write to a temporary file. In particular, this has been done inside the `_on_task_done` function. It is not the most elegant way, but it works, the memory used is very low and the execution time is the same.